# Python Amazon Product Api not able to get image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm using [python amazon product api](https://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/operations.html#lookup-and-search-operations) and I can't seem to get the url for the image of the product.

Here is my code so far

```
for book in amz_api.item_search('Books', Keywords='cookies', ResponseGroup='Large', limit=10):
        print book.ItemAttributes.Large
```

But I get this reply

```
AttributeError: no such child: {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Large
```

Any help would be apprecicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the image URLs, you can try to change your code to use one of the following:

```
print book.SmallImage.URL
print book.MediumImage.URL
print book.LargeImage.URL
```

The error is because there is no "Large" attribute in [ItemAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_ItemAttributes.html). The image URLs are available in a different part of the response.

The [Large Response Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Large.html) (ResponseGroup='Large') returns a lot of data. According to the docs it's for demonstration purposes and not intended for production applications. To make your code production ready, you might need a different approach, such as the [Images Response Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Images.html) (ResponseGroup='Images').

Also, the python type for the book variable in the above code is:

```
<type 'lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement'>
```

While debugging, you can look at all the data available in book using something like this:

```
from lxml import objectify

print(objectify.dump(book))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get price, images and title info in a request rather than specifying groups?